# Alighnment issues on Virtual Keyboard popup in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, alignment, virtual-keyboard

I have a login screen with some textfields, textboxs, buttons and having the background image to the screen. Now the issue is on touch devices when virtual keyboard is popups, the screen shrinks with its background image and all components alignment get disturbed. I have also enabled the Vertical scroll to the screen but still alignment get disturbed. Please can one help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you are using Display.getHeight() for the alignment of UI component. And after displaying virtual keyboard, Display.getHeight() not return the actual screen height. It's return the height excluding the keyboard height.

Comment: Yes, but whats the way to avoid this issue?

Comment: you can get the Display height at the starting of the application in static variable and then use that variable throughout application.